# Retrieving x number of random objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql

I'm just trying to load 5 random objects in a rails controller

```
Thing.all(:limit => 5, :order => "RANDOM()")
```

Is that the least expensive way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

What you have asked the db to do is: go order the entire thing table in a random order... then grab me five of them. If your thing table has a lot of rows... that's a very expensive operation.

A better option (if the ids are auto-increment and thus likely concurrent) is to generate a set of random ids within the id-range for your thing table and go fetch these individual things by those ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way:

```
Thing.all.sample(5)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is "the least expensive way to do it"?

Comment: Yeah, not sure it is. Sample only works on a complete set (it randomly orders the array and pulls out the first N that you ask for).
This relies on you pulling out the entire set of Things...